# Failing chai test for async function throwing an error

Tags: node.js, async-await, mocha.js, chai

I'd like to test if my "missing_body" has been thrown. But my test only show the error which has been caught, but the expect test still fails. Could you help me understand it?

```
async add(req) {
   const db = _.get(req, 'app.locals.db');
   const bookDescription = req.body;
   logger.info('books.add', bookDescription);
   if (_.isEmpty(bookDescription)) {
     throw new Error('missing_body');
   }
   [...]
}

describe('+add(req)', function() {
    it('should fail because of missing body', async function() {
      const req = {
        body: {},
      };

      expect(await this.ctrl.add(req)).to.throw(new Error('missing_body'));
    });
});
```

[image: failing tests]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And another mistake is to provide an object method (or any stand-alone function that relies on this) as the target of the assertion. Doing so is problematic because the this context will be lost when the function is invoked by .throw; there’s no way for it to know what this is supposed to be. There are two ways around this problem. One solution is to wrap the method or function call inside of another function. Another solution is to use bind. If you test sync function.

```
expect(function () { cat.meow(); }).to.throw();  // Function expression
expect(() => cat.meow()).to.throw();             // ES6 arrow function
expect(cat.meow.bind(cat)).to.throw();           // Bind
```

But in the asynchronous `(await add()).to.throw(Error)` will never work: if fails() rejects, an error is thrown, and .to.throw(Error) is never executed. So you need to do something like this:

```
it('should fail', async () => {
  await expect(this.ctrl.add(req.body)).to.be.rejectedWith(Error);
})
```

**SOLUTION:**

```
async add(req) {
  const db = _.get(req, 'app.locals.db');
  const bookDescription = req.body;
  logger.info('books.add', bookDescription);
  if (_.isEmpty(bookDescription)) {
    throw new Error('missing_body');
  }
  [...]
}

describe('+add(req)', function() {
  it('should fail because of missing body', async function() {
    const req = {
      body: {},
    };

  await expect(this.ctrl.add(req.body)).to.be.rejectedWith(Error);
  });
});
```

Comment: It is not an error if _.empty returns true, that what I want to check. So in my test i'll stick with `this.ctrl.add(req)`. What I was doing wrong is, placing my await inside the expect and not on the expect. Thanks! You solved my problem!

Answer (score 0):

If you are expecting catch some Error you will need to assert inside a catch block. You are trying to assert an arror creating a new Error instance. If you are using syncronous programming, so you need to catch your errors like:

```
    it('should fail because of missing body', async function() {
      const req = {
        body: {},
      };

      try {
        await this.ctrl.add(req)
      } catch(e) {
         expect(e.message).to.equal('missing_body');
      }
    });
```